# How to manage unions and bit-fields

Tags: c, bit-fields, fixed-point

I have been trying to create a program that adds two positive fixed point numbers whose whole part is 5 bits and its decimal part is 3 bits but I have not succeeded, I know that it can be achieved with the handling of bit fields and unions but I have not found the goal. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: add your code to this question

Comment: Fixed point addition is literally the `+` operator between two integers. Bitfields only get in the way. So your question is about how to implement an approach that complicates your original problem..

Comment: @harold op says "decimal part is 3 bits" so it isn’t integer

Comment: @Marichyasana yes it is, that's how fixed point arithmetic works. Here they're just integers that are implicitly scaled by 1/8, that scale doesn't matter for addition. Multiplication and division take some special care though.

Answer (score 1):

Let `a` be an integer object that represents a number *a* using a fixed-point representation with three fraction bits. Then `a` = 8•*a*, or, conversely, *a* = `a`/8.

Similarly, let `b` be an integer object that represents a number *b* with the same representation.

Then, since *a* = `a`/8 and *b* = `b`/8, we have *a* + *b* = `a`/8 + `b`/8 = `a+b`/8.

Therefore, the representation of the sum of the number represented by `a` and the number represented by `b` can be computed with `a+b`.

Answer (score 0):

The bit fields in `C` programming can be defined using `struct` as shown below for task you want to perform.

```
struct decimalPoint
{
    unsigned int wholePart:5;
    unsigned int decimalPart:3;
};
```

Now since the way to definition of your data is ready you can perform addition of this data and store the result back to the same structure.